# Redux action uncaught in reducer because of mutated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

You can assume the following variables:

```
click = true

categories = [
  {title: "all", onClick: false},
  {title: "video", onClick: false},
  {title: "gif", onClick: false},
  {title: "website", onClick: false}
]

finalCategories = [
  {title: "all", onClick: true},
  {title: "video", onClick: true},
  {title: "gif", onClick: true},
  {title: "website", onClick: true}
]
```

I have a set of redux actions here:

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';
import {beginAjaxCall, ajaxCallError} from './ajaxStatusActions';
import * as Utils from './utils/dashboardActionsUtils';

export function updateCategoriesSuccess(categories) {
  return {type: actionTypes.UPDATE_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS, categories};
}

export function categoryAllClick(categories, click) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(beginAjaxCall());
    const finalCategories = Utils.updateMenuOnAll(categories, click);
    dispatch(updateCategoriesSuccess(finalCategories));
  };
}
```

Where:

```
export function updateMenuOnAll(menu, click) {
  const finalMenu = Object.assign([], menu);
  if (click) {
    finalMenu.map(item => item.onClick = true);
  } else {
    finalMenu.map(item => item.onClick = false);
  }
  return finalMenu;
}
```

However, when I call `categoryAllClick(categories, click)` the `actionTypes.UPDATE_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS` does not get caught by my reducer:

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function dashboardReducer(state = initialState.dashboard, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case actionTypes.UPDATE_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {categories: action.categories});

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I am assuming this is because when I attempt this action, I get the error message:

```
2 Uncaught Error: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path `dashboard.categories.0.onClick`. This may cause incorrect behavior. (http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#never-mutate-reducer-arguments)
```

Is there something I am doing wrong in the updateMenuOnAll exported function to cause this state mutation? I thought using `Object.assign()` would avoid this issue. Thanks!

**EDIT**

The following react component is the one calling `categoryAllClick`, when the appropriate div is clicked:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as dashboardActions from '../../../../../actions/dashboardActions';

class CheckboxItem extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    const {menu, title, type, categoryAllClick, tagAllClick, actions} = this.props;
    if (type === "categories") {
      if (title === "all") {
        actions.categoryAllClick(menu, !categoryAllClick);
      } else {
        actions.updateCategories(title, menu);
      }
    } else if (type === "tags") {
      if (title === "all") {
        actions.tagAllClick(menu, !tagAllClick);
      } else {
        actions.updateTags(title, menu);
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="div-common-menu-item" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        // Child componenets here
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CheckboxItem.propTypes = {
  menu: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  categories: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  tags: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  categoryAllClick: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  tagAllClick: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    categories: state.dashboard.categories,
    tags: state.dashboard.tags,
    categoryAllClick: state.dashboard.categoryAllClick,
    tagAllClick: state.dashboard.tagAllClick
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(dashboardActions, dispatch)
  };
}

const connectedStateAndProps = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
export default connectedStateAndProps(CheckboxItem);
```

Comment: Instead of Object.assign() you can use the [object spread operator](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator), but you are correct, you are not mutating the state there.

Comment: Not sure if it will fix your error, but you can prevent the mutation by replacing the body of `updateMenuOnAll` with `return menu.map((item) => ({...item, onClick: click}));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the `updateMenuOnAll` function. Rewriting it to the below fixed the problem. Thanks everyone!

```
export function updateMenuOnAll(menu, click) {
  return menu.map(item => ({title: item.title, onClick: click}));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `updateMenuOnAll` function  is wrong, in three ways:

- It's mutating the items when you loop over them
- `map()` returns a new array, but you're ignoring that return value
- Using `Object.assign()` is not the right way to copy an array.

A better approach would be:

```
export function updateMenuOnAll(menu, click) {
  const newOnClick = !!click;

  const finalMenu = menu.map(item => ({...item, onClick : newOnClick}));
  return finalMenu;
}
```

Comment: Why does it matter if its mutating the items, if the items its mutating are part of finalMenu, a new copy of menu?

Comment: Because you're only making a shallow copy, not a deep copy, so all the items in the original array are also in the copied array.  Also, `Object.assign()` is not the right way to copy an array.  I've updated my answer with a correct approach that should fix all the issues I listed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the code you have in the function "Utils.updateMenuOnAll", but if it is mutating your object categories you might see that error.

Comment: try "finalMenu.map(item => {title: item.title, onClick: true})"

Answer (score 1):

That's because you should not call `categoryAllClick(categories, click)` directly, but use a dispatcher instead. For example, if you are react, using `react-redux` you "connect" your component (using `import { connect } from 'react-redux';`) passing your function in the `mapDispatchToProps` argument.

Having that said, you are correct to assume that using `Object.assign` is not mutating your state.